# How sort by sub query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a query like this.

```
select * 
from tbl_post where id IN (select post_id from tbl_front_post 
where section = 'shrestha' order by id desc)`
```

Now I want to order according to `id` of `tbl_front_post`.

Comment: This cannot be answered as stated. The `IN` operator can find any number of records in `tbl_front_post` that match section = 'shrestha'. Each one of those is an equally valid record to pick the `id`, so asking to order the outer query by it makes no sense. You have to define the question better.

Answer (score 0):

you have to join both table first after than you can able to order based on tbl_front_post

```
select tbl_post.* 
from tbl_post 
    left join tbl_front_post on tbl_front_post .post_id = tbl_post.id 
where id IN (select post_id from tbl_front_post where section = 'shrestha') 
oreder by tbl_front_post.id
```

Comment: Thnks but some error occurs `#1052 - Column 'id' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous
Open new phpMyAdmin window`

Comment: same error. Did make any effect then previous query

Comment: whats is an error? and where is your query? show me that i can may be able to help you

Comment: `#1052 - Column 'id' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous`